# fs.readdirSync, how do I get the subfolders in path?

Tags: javascript, node.js

## how do I get the subfolders?

**Path** dist/docs/:

- 2006/Art1
- 2006/Art2
- 2008/Art1
- offline
- test

```js
const distPath = 'dist/docs/';

function getDirectories(distPath) {
  return fs.readdirSync(distPath).filter(function (file) {
    return fs.statSync(distPath + '/' + file).isDirectory();
  }).filter(function (distPath) {
    return distPath != 'test' && distPath != 'offline';
  });
}

let articlePath = getDirectories(distPath);
```

**unexpected**

> '2006', '2006', '2008'

**expected**

> '2006/Art1', '2006/Art2', '2008/Art1'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fs.readdirSync` reads the content of only one directory; if you find an entry is a subdirectory and you need to read the content of given subdirectory, you need to call `fs.readdirSync` on the subdirectory as well.

It seems you need something recursive.

```
function deepGetDirectories(distPath) {
    return fs.readdirSync(distPath).filter(function (file) {
        return fs.statSync(distPath + '/' + file).isDirectory();
    }).reduce(function(all, subDir) {
        return [...all, ...fs.readdirSync(distPath + '/' + subDir).map(e => subDir + '/' + e)]
    }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Thanks [Daniele Ricci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4690946/daniele-ricci) for your [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62246565/9050912)!**

```js
function getDirectories(distPath) {
  return fs.readdirSync(distPath).filter(function (file) {
    return fs.statSync(distPath + '/' + file).isDirectory();
  }).filter(function (distPath) {
    return distPath != 'autoren' && distPath != 'offline';
  }).reduce(function (all, subDir) {
    return [...all, ...fs.readdirSync(distPath + '/' + subDir).map(e => subDir + '/' + e)]
  }, []).filter(function (file) {
    return fs.statSync(distPath + '/' + file).isDirectory();
  });
}

let articlePath = getDirectories(distPath);
```

**I used his code suggestion:**

```js
.reduce(function (all, subDir) {
    return [...all, ...fs.readdirSync(distPath + '/' + subDir).map(e => subDir + '/' + e)]
  }, []).filter(function (file) {
    return fs.statSync(distPath + '/' + file).isDirectory();
  });
```